# Tic Tac Toe in python keeps returning int error

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a simple tic tac toe game in python. This is my code so far but when i run it it, it asks for a spot to select I enter a number and it displays the board but then it returns this error:
line 32, in 
    input = int(input("Select a spot: "))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

please help how I can resolve this as the user has to select a number. i'm using python 3.

```
import random
board = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
def show():
print (board[0]," | ", board[1]," | ", board[2])
print ("----------------")
print (board[3]," | ", board[4]," | ", board[5])
print ("----------------")
print (board[6]," | ", board[7]," | ", board[8])

def checkLine(char, spot1, spot2, spot3):
if board[spot1] == char and board[spot2] == char and board[spot3] == char:
    return True

def checkAll(char):
if checkLine(char, 0, 1, 2):
    True
if checkLine(char, 1, 4, 7):
    True
if checkLine(char, 2, 5, 8):
    True
if checkLine(char, 6, 7, 8):
    True
if checkLine(char, 3, 4, 5):
    True
if checkLine(char, 2, 4, 6):
    True
if checkLine(char, 0, 4, 6):
    True

while True:

input = int(input("Select a spot: "))


if board[input] != 'x' and board[input] != 'o':
    board[input] = 'x'

    if checkAll('x') == True:
        print("-- X WINS --")
        break;

    random.seed()
    opponent = random.randint(0,8)

    while True:
        if board[opponent] != 'o' and board[opponent] != 'x':
            board[opponent] = 'o'

            if checkAll('o') == True:
                print("-- O WINS --")
                break;


            break;
 else:
    print ('This spot is taken')
 show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign an integer to `input`:

```
input = int(input("Select a spot: "))
```

Don't do that. Once you use the name `input` for a different object, the built-in function `input` will not be available anymore. So in the second loop `input` is not a function as before but an integer.

Use a different name:

```
user_input = int(input("Select a spot: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first time this line runs you assign an integer value to `input` and second time you call `input("")` it gets error because you call an integer! The problem would be solved by changing variable name.

To solve it you can simply change the variable name:

```
inp = int(input("Select a spot: "))
```

Comment: How is your answer different from mine posted 5 minutes ago?

Comment: Thanks, I've sorted it.

Comment: @lisaturner you must mark an answer as correct if your problem is solved.